# SELECT SUM(FieldName) FROM TableName between Column_Value and Column_Value;

Tags: mysql, sql

Everyone. I have SQL Query Questions.
can I calculate the values between two columns.?
for. example. I have a table Book;

```
CREATE TABLE Book(

    ID int,
    DateOfSellBook Date,
    Book varchar(255),
    SellBook int (255),
    
);
INSERT INTO `book`(`ID`, `Date`, `Book Title`, `Sell Book`) VALUES (1, 3/2/2021, Java,10);
INSERT INTO `book`(`ID`, `Date`, `Book Title`, `Sell Book`) VALUES (2,3/3/2021,Java,10);
INSERT INTO `book`(`ID`, `Date`, `Book Title`, `Sell Book`) VALUES (3,3/4/2021,javascript,10);
INSERT INTO `book`(`ID`, `Date`, `Book Title`, `Sell Book`) VALUES (4,3/5/2021,php,10);
```

between ID 1 and 3, How Many Books Sell ?.
SELECT SUM(FieldName) FROM TableName between Column_Value and Column_Value; but it's not working for me please help

Comment: Replace SUM by COUNT, and show us the query you made if you have more questions

Comment: I'm confused. If this is MySQL, those are not valid dates. And strings must be quoted.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT count(distinct book_number) FROM book 
where id between 1 and 4
```

This query will give you list of unique book_number between id 1 and 4. To get all the book_number (if there is a book named 'book a' two times then it will be counted two times):

```
SELECT count(book_number) FROM book 
where id between 1 and 4
```

Comment: Thank you So Much @Kazi Mohammad Ali Nur, its worked to me